# ListView ObservableCollection binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I'm having problem with binding Collection do ListView.

```
 public static ObservableCollection<ParagonViewClass> mparagonViewList = new ObservableCollection<ParagonViewClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<ParagonViewClass> paragonViewList
        {
            get
            {
                return mparagonViewList;
            }
        }
```

In method, when user add new item, I'm adding it to list:

```
paragonViewList.Insert(0, newPar);
```

Also tried with mparagonViewList.Insert(0, newPar);

Itemssource in xaml file:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="paragonListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding paragonViewList}" .../>
```

@EDIT: Listview have DataTemplate (Grid with labels - im prettu sure that binding is ok, becouse it works with just simply setting myListVIew.ItemsSource = myLis;)

It looks like when I click on product to add to listview it does insert to database, but I cannot see that product on listview. Probably there's little stupid problem, but I cant really find it ;)

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you supplied, it is hard to figure out what you are doing wrong, if anything. So, I have thrown together a little sample application that works (from the WPF point of view anyway).

My model is called ItemModel, rather than ParagonViewClass, and is defined as follows

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel() { }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20799346.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:common="clr-namespace:StackOverflow.Common;assembly=StackOverflow.Common"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="Add Item" Click="AddItem_OnClick" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type common:ItemModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Note the DataContext being bound to RelativeSource Self, allowing the code behind to be used as the ViewModel. I usually prefer to create a separate ViewModel class but this approach has its advantages as one can event directly from a control into the ViewModel, rather than mucking around with commands.

The code behind, now the view model, looks like

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get { return items ?? (items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>()); } }

    private void AddItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add(new ItemModel() { Text = Items.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) });
    }
}
```

I have utilised a lazy load technique on the Items property. It will only be instantiated when it is accessed. For simplicity, when the Add Item button is clicked, I am adding a new item with its text set to the count of the Items collection.

You should be able to past this code into a new WPF application project, fix the namespacing in the xaml file and run it.

Now, as hinted at above by Rohit Vats, the Items property does not require a Setter. The ObservableCollection itself notifies the WPF binding subsystem when an item has been added or removed via both the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces, both of which it implements.

I know this does not directly answer your question but with out further information (ie code) about the original problem, it is not possible to know what is going wrong.

Hopefully the example helps.

*NOTE: I have removed exception management for brevity.*